# Kubernetes API Server: Unable to listen for secure

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup Kubernetes for the first time. I am following the Fedora Manual installation guide: 
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config.html

I checked the logs of my API server and am getting this error:

```
 server.go:464] Unable to listen for secure (open /var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.crt: no such file or directory); will try again.
```

I assume it needs some sort of cert but the installation guide doesnt mention anything about this. Here is what my apiserver config file looks like

```
# The address on the local server to listen to.
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--address=0.0.0.0"

# The port on the local server to listen on.
KUBE_API_PORT="--port=8080"

# Port node listen on
KUBELET_PORT="--kubelet_port=10250"

# Location of the etcd cluster
#KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd_servers=http://vagrant-master:4001"
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001"

# Address range to use for services
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"

# default admission control policies
KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="--admission_control=NamespaceAutoProvision,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota"

# Add your own!
KUBE_API_ARGS="--service_account_key_file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/serviceaccount.key"
```

Here is my service status

```
kube-apiserver.service - Kubernetes API Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-apiserver.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-08-24 15:03:07 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
 Main PID: 13663 (kube-apiserver)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kube-apiserver.service
           └─13663 /usr/bin/kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 --address=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --kubelet_port=10250 --allow_privileged=false --service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16 --admission_control=NamespaceAutoProvision,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota --service_account_key_file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/serviceaccount.key
```

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the kube-apiserver process tries to open a secure (https) server port on port 6443 using credentials from the directory `/var/run/kubernetes`. If you want to disable the secure port, you can pass `--secure-port=0` which should make your error go away. Alternatively, you can [manually create certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/certificates/) for your cluster so that the process is able to successfully open the secure port.

Comment: github link doesn't exist

Comment: Yeah, it's been a few years. It looks like this documentation now lives at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/certificates/

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in kube-apiserver. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1201965